# How to pull git repository using Rugged ruby gem

Tags: ruby, libgit2, rugged

How do I pull changes from remote repo using Rugged ruby gem. Most of question on this topic are outdated as api has changed. I am using a simple repo with nothing complex. I found below code on one of the stackoverflow question but unfortunately its outdated

```
remote = repo.remotes['origin']
remote.fetch(credentials: credentials)
remote.save
```

Also `remote.fetch` gives `{:total_objects=>0, :indexed_objects=>0, :received_objects=>0, :local_objects=>0, :total_deltas=>0, :indexed_deltas=>0, :received_bytes=>0}` and no changes are pulled

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rugged/0.27.7/Rugged/Remote#fetch-instance_method) have this example:

```
remote = Rugged::Remote.lookup(@repo, 'origin')
remote.fetch({
  transfer_progress: lambda { |total_objects, indexed_objects, received_objects, local_objects, total_deltas, indexed_deltas, received_bytes|
    # ...
  }
})
```

Comment: That would just do fetch index and not pull actual content.

Comment: Pull is just fetch+merge. So if you know how to do merges you're good.

Comment: This issue deserves a proper answer. The above is not helpful.